# Eclipse not recognising Java-17

Tags: java, eclipse, java-17

Hi today I installed java 17 and eclipse(with latest version- 2021‑09). But after all configuration it is showing JavaSE-16 as jdk version. I ignored it and started writing a program with sealed classes. Then it is showing an error. I managed to solve the problem by installing the Java-17 support plugin from eclipse marketplace. Is it possible in eclipse without installing anything.

Comment: 1 vote for having the same problem.

Comment: No, it isn't possible without installing anything - Java 17 support is in the patch. Eclipse 2021-12 will have full Java 17 support included.

Comment: Generally, don't expect tooling support for something a day after it has been released.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eclipse 2021-09 code completion not showing all methods and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357171/eclipse-2021-09-code-completion-not-showing-all-methods-and-classes)

Answer (score 6):

The release notes state this:

> Supports Java 17, including Pattern Matching for Switch (Preview),
> Sealed Classes, and more **via Eclipse Marketplace**

That means currently you have to install the plugin, later support will be included.
You might also want to read this: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.21/jdt.php

Answer (score 2):

Install java 17 plugin from [this](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-17-support-eclipse-2021-09-421) link.  Then your likely to have a [content assist error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357171/eclipse-2021-09-code-completion-not-showing-all-methods-and-classes). Fix it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69381206/17022570) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The support should be official with Eclipse 4.22 (Q4 2021)

> ### [Java 17](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/jdt.php#Java_17)
>
> Java 17 is out and Eclipse JDT supports Java 17 in 4.22.
>
> The release notably includes the following Java 17 features:
>
> - [JEP 306](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/306): Restore Always-Strict Floating-Point Semantics.
> - [JEP 406](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406): Pattern Matching for switch (Preview).
> - [JEP 409](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/409): Sealed Classes (Final).
>
> Please note that preview option should be on for preview language features.   >For an informal introduction of the support, please refer to J**[ava 17 Examples wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java17/Examples)**.