# Eclipse 2021-09 code completion not showing all methods and classes

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist, eclipse-2021-09

Hi some days before I updated my eclipse 2021-06 to 2021-09 and after that its code completion will not show all the methods and classes. For example if I type `frame.setS`, then it is showing no default proposals.

[image]

But At the same time when I type `frame.setC` and press ctrl+space, it is working This is the

[image]

Also in my settings everything is checked.

[image]

##### What I have tried

1. I searched the web and found many stack overflow questions and I tried the answers. But it didn't work
2. I deleted the `.metedata` folder and uninstalled and reinstalled eclipse for 5 times.
3. I tried installing eclipse from installer and zip.

Is this a bug or something.

I have also installed the java 17 plugin from eclipse marketplace.

### Edit

In eclipse `2021-12 (4.22)` which released yesterday (08-12-21),
`java.awt.*` is not filtered out. So no problem. Also it has Java-17 support..

Comment: Never ever delete the `.metadata` folder, that's a hoax spread on Stack Overflow. When you cannot restore it, use a fresh workspace. The Java 17 plugin is a preview/BETA, not the official release. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and make sure it has been reported to Eclipse. In the last to versions bigger changes has been made in the content assist to handle incomplete code, and there are known issues in Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21): see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Please show a minimal reproducible example that works without the Java 17 plugin.

Comment: @howlger install eclipse 2021-09 and try you can reproduce it. Also I subscribed your youtube channel  so that I can see videos about eclipse.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21) everything of `java.awt.*` is filtered out in the content assist by default.

To disable this default filter, go to the **preferences** (*Window > Preferences*; in macOS in the application menu) ***Java > Appearance > Type Filters*** and **uncheck** the checkbox **`java.awt.*`**.

I reported it to Eclipse and it has been **fixed** within two weeks, so it will be in the next release **Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22)** that will be released on December 8, 2021 (and also sooner in the milestone builds starting with M2):

- [**Eclipse bug 576549** - [content assist] Missing proposals in Swing, etc. because of java.awt.* type filter enabled by default](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=576549).

Comment: Thanks Sir It Worked. You Saved My life. I was going to install NetBeans and you saved eclipse. Thanks sir thanks. I cannot explain my happiness Thank you sir Thank you. Now my Eclipse is working fine.  Sir god bless you.

Comment: Thanks. The other default choices here explains why JDK Panama classes vanished from my Eclipse after I also upgraded, as the default filter hides `jdk.*`.

Comment: Sir now in eclipse 2021-12 everything is okay.

Comment: @JFan Great. Not all, but most of the bugs I reported to Eclipse were fixed quickly. And this one was even reported without a patch. I also covered it in my Eclipse Java IDE 2021-12 video: https://youtu.be/3W9bvidcO20?t=172