# Esclipse IDE java.awt and java.swing suggestions missing?

Tags: java

Today I reset my pc and reinstalled Eclipse. I am using jdk-17 instead on 16 like last time because I just download the latest version. And then the java awt and swing is no longer suggesting and everything has to be typed. What do I do now?

[I tried to implement ActionListener but its is not suggesting me to import java.awt.Event.ActionLister][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHnNe.png
[Same thing happened here the this.add(button) is not suggesting and I have to cancel the suggestion and type full][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwwvB.png

Comment: I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357171/eclipse-2021-09-code-completion-not-showing-all-methods-and-classes/69381206#69381206) about this. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a question about this. See the accepted answer [Eclipse 2021-09 code completion not showing all methods and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357171/eclipse-2021-09-code-completion-not-showing-all-methods-and-classes/69381206#69381206)

This is the accepted answer

Comment: thanks @JFan it worked