# Java eclipse some of the shortcut for importing classes are missing

Tags: java, eclipse, class, user-interface, import

I have a problem that I can't solve and it's not something like a loop problem or any problem-solving type one

I just want to create a basic GUI but whatever I do I can't import ActionListener, KeyListener, or any of the Layouts like GridLayout

[image]

[image]

[image]

To fix this problem I need to literally write 'import java.awt.evet.ActionListener;'
And lastly, I deleted and re-uploaded eclipse with my codes but it's still there please help me

Comment: Eclipse 2021-09 filters out java.awt.*, this will be reverted in 2021-12. See the duplicate for how to clear the filter

Comment: THE PROPER SOLUTION IS OVER HERE !!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69357171/eclipse-2021-09-code-completion-not-showing-all-methods-and-classes

Answer (score 0):

you must
import java.awt.*
import javax.swings